# How to unload a single unit from warp prism/medivac without mouse actions

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to be able to unload the first unit on a dropship via hotkey, but apparently this isn't possible as the default "unload all" action only allows dropping after you click either the dropship itself or a location on the ground.
Any tips to avoid the mouse click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there is no way to start unloading without a mouse click.

The easiest way to unload a single unit is to click the unit's icon on Medivac'c cargo display. This way you at least won't need to cancel the unloading of remaining units.

Comment: damn, i will attemp some sort of mouse macro first before giving up then.

Comment: @user2464424 If you mean binding of a keyboard key to some mouse actions, that is also hardly doable. The problem is that you still need to position the pointer either on ground or on the medivac - which can be anywhere on the screen. Maybe if you are able to save pointer position, put it on top of cargo display, click, and then restore pointer position... Hey, we may be on to something here :-)

Comment: @OrcJMR you could probably assign the transport to a hotkey control group (cntrl + 1, etc)

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer  Of course, but I selecting a medivac is not a problem, as I understand. It is unloading a unit at current medivac position without moving the mouse.